# Accessing Values in a Class Similar to boost::any

Tags: c++, oop, derived-class, boost-any

I'm making a simple `boost::any`-like class for educational purposes, but I can't figure out how to access the stored value.  I can set the value perfectly, but when I try to access any member in the "holder" class the compiler just complains that the member wasn't found in the class it was derived from.  I can't declare the members as `virtual` because of the templates.

Here's the relevant code:

```
class Element
{
    struct ValueStorageBase
    {
    };

    template <typename Datatype>
    struct ValueStorage: public ValueStorageBase
    {
        Datatype Value;

        ValueStorage(Datatype InitialValue)
        {
            Value = InitialValue;
        }
    };

    ValueStorageBase* StoredValue;

public:

    template <typename Datatype>
    Element(Datatype InitialValue)
    {
        StoredValue = new ValueStorage<Datatype>(InitialValue);
    }

    template <typename Datatype>
    Datatype Get()
    {
        return StoredValue->Value; // Error: "struct Element::ValueStorageBase" has no member named "Value."
    }
};
```

Comment: boost::any is pretty much useless in practical terms, i haven't seen it being used in any production project for in like 10+ years. boost::variant<> or similar classes is the standard way of storing values of different types.

Comment: @Maxim: I agree with you, I also never saw `boost::any` used. But `boost::function` or similar type erasure classes have their use. Perhaps `boost::any` is too general for C++ type system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fine to add virtual functions to templates- just the functions themselves cannot be templates. A templated class or struct can still have virtual functions just fine. You need to use the magic of dynamic_cast.

```
class Element
{
    struct ValueStorageBase
    {
        virtual ~ValueStorageBase() {}
    };

    template <typename Datatype>
    struct ValueStorage: public ValueStorageBase
    {
        Datatype Value;

        ValueStorage(Datatype InitialValue)
        {
            Value = InitialValue;
        }
    };

    ValueStorageBase* StoredValue;

public:

    template <typename Datatype>
    Element(Datatype InitialValue)
    {
        StoredValue = new ValueStorage<Datatype>(InitialValue);
    }

    template <typename Datatype>
    Datatype Get()
    {
        if(ValueStorage<DataType>* ptr = dynamic_cast<ValueStorage<DataType>*>(StoredValue)) {
            return ptr->Value;
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("Incorrect type!"); // Error: "struct Element::ValueStorageBase" has no member named "Value."
    }
};
```

If you change Get to return a `Datatype*` you can return `NULL` instead of throwing. You also haven't handled the memory of the previous value of `StoredValue`, but I'm leaving that up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast it to `ValueStorage` first.
Also add virtual destructur to ValueStorageBase  class, to have polymorphic class. Without it you can't runtime check if your casting is OK :).

After it you can write:

```
template <typename Datatype>
    Datatype Element_cast()
    {
        //throw exception for a wrong cast
        if(typeid(*StoredValue)!=typeid(ValueStorage<Datatype>) )
               throw exception;

        //we already checked, that our type casting is OK,
        //So no need for dynamic_cast anymore
        return static_cast<ValueStorage*> (StoredValue)->value;
    }
```

Comment: +1 In addition, I believe `ValueStorageBase` has to be polymorphic so that `typeid(*StoredValue)` returns a `type_info` reference corresponding to the *dynamic* type and not just the base class. It should be polymorphic anyways so it can be polymorphically deleted in the any-class' destructor.

Comment: Why not use a `dynamic_cast` instead of `typeid` + `static_cast` ?

Comment: @Matthieu M. what's a difference? Probobly yeah, dynamic_cast will save few characters :)

Comment: performance-wise ? no difference I guess, but it would be more idiomatic.